# How can I use ESSTIX font in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-operators

I am quite interested in the ESSTIX symbol font. The question is, how can I use symbols from this font set? In particular, I am quite interested in those symbols in ESSTIX6 (especially the integral sign). Is there a way to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `xelatex` or `pdflatex`

Comment: Do you want Esstix specifically, or its successors, STIX and STIX Two?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [`esstix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/esstix) package on CTAN.  However, it does not come ready-to-use and was last updated in the twentieth century.

There is a newer version, STIX, a STIX Two font, and an improved OpenType version of the STIX 1 font, XITS.  So, I would suggest you actually do this:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{XITS}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

If you're forced to use the legacy encodings, you probably want `\usepackage{stix2}`.  STIX is more up-to-date and has an extremely large repertoire of symbols.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. What I want to do is to use some symbols from esstix (in particular, the ``light'' integral sign provided by ESSTIX6) without changing fonts for others. I know STIX and STIX 2 will change the font used in the whole document, so it may not suit my needs. Anyway, thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Xintong XITS Math and STIX Two both have [alternative integral signs](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/fonts/stix2-otf/STIX_2.0.0_stylistic_sets.pdf) that you can load with `\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C}, StylisticSet=8, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}`. You could load the integral signs from any other OpenType math font the same way. Otherwise, you would need to load ESSTIX6 as a symbol font and `\DeclareMathSymbol`.